# SQL IIF on multiple columns

Tags: sql, ms-access, iif

new week new problem..

I need o find out who is on holiday this month. 
I have this tables:

worker - id, name, forename

holiday - idworker, from, to, idstatus

now i need a query which gives me something like this:

`n     | fn    | idstat | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 ..
max   | muster| 1      | t | t | t | f | f | f ..
max   | muster| 2      | f | f | f | f | t | t ..
peter | pan   | 1      | f | t | f | f | f | t ..`

the numbers are the days in the month and
t/f is true false, so if thex are on holiday or not..

Right now i have this code:

```
SELECT worker.forename + " " + worker.name AS Name, holiday.IdStatus,
IIF(#08/01/2014# BETWEEN holiday.from AND holiday.to, 'True', 'FALSE') AS 1,
IIF(#08/02/2014# BETWEEN holiday.from AND holiday.to, 'True', 'FALSE') AS 2,
IIF(#08/03/2014# BETWEEN holiday.from AND holiday.to, 'True', 'FALSE') AS 3,
IIF(#08/04/2014# BETWEEN holiday.from AND holiday.to, 'True', 'FALSE') AS 4,
IIF(#08/05/2014# BETWEEN holiday.from AND holiday.to, 'True', 'FALSE') AS 5,
IIF(#08/06/2014# BETWEEN holiday.from AND holiday.to, 'True', 'FALSE') AS 6,
FROM worker LEFT JOIN holiday ON worker.Id = holiday.idworker
```

but this just uses one column in holiday so there are multiple columns for one person..

someone got an idea? >_>'

EDIT:

sample Data: 
worker:

`Id - Name - Forname
1  - Pan  - Peter
2  - Max  - Muster`

holiday:

`IdWorker - from     - to       - ids - comment
1        - 8/1/2014 - 8/2/2014 - 1   - has holiday from 1.8.2014 to 2.8.2014
1        - 8/5/2014 - 8/6/2014 - 2   - wants holiday from 5.8.2014 to 6.8.2014
1        - 8/4/2014 - 8/4/2014 - 1   - has holiday on 4.08.2014`

idstatus(ids):
1 is has holiday
2 is wants holiday

now my result should be this:

`n     | fn    | idstat | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 ..
max   | muster| 1      | f | f | f | f | f | f ..
peter | pan   | 2      | f | f | f | f | t | t ..
peter | pan   | 1      | t | t | f | t | f | f ..`

Comment: Could you edit your post with some data that you have in your table?

Comment: i don't understand your question. You need to provide sample data and expected result !

Comment: @PaulFrancis do you get it now? 
dont know how i should explain it better..

Comment: @hoangnnm same for u.

Comment: So as I understand your request you want a column for every day of the month.  It might be useful to know why -- this is not typical of an output from an SQL server (a table with 30+ columns)  Is it possible to look at how this is going to be used... maybe there is a better way.

Comment: i wanna build a web application with an calender. 
for that i need the data in one row. 

But i think i will do it on code with c#. and combine the columns which are multiple..

Answer (score 0):

You can use crosstab, but it's really clumsy if you want to use the results somewhere else. If you are desperate for this kind of solution, you can select all days, join them with holidays table, put IIf for each date (`IIf(date >= startdate and date <= end date)`), then pivot it.

Comment: This really lacks a clear definition as an answer. I suggest you edit your answer to provide more information, and apply your answer towards the question, explicitly.

Comment: well if i got it right this is the exact same thing i did.. 
so it doesnt work at all..